# How to force Webpage to navigate to login page rather than automatically singing in?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

The MSAL library launches the login screen within the chrome browser in the Xamarin.Android app. After logging in successfully, the app redirects to the main page as expected. The below is a snippet of the login code being used:

```
Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult auth = null;
App.PrepareAuthClient(authType);

string policy = App.SignInPolicyB2C;
string authority = App.AuthoritySignInB2C;

(...)

auth = await App.AuthenticationClient.AcquireTokenAsync(
                App.ApiScope,
                GetUserByPolicy(App.AuthenticationClient.Users, policy),
                App.UiParent);
```

However, the issue occurs after logging out. Once we log out and then try to log back in, instead of the chrome browser displaying the login page to input the username and password, it will automatically log the user in and redirect them to the main page without even loading the login page. The browser simply opens up and loads for a few seconds and then redirects the user to the main page successfully logging them in even after having a user explicitly log out.

We tried adding *prompt = force login* but that didn't seem to help. The only way the user gets the login page again is after we manually clear the chrome browser cache.

Is there a way to clear the cache upon signing out? Or is there another way to force the browser to display the login page even if there is cache information?